# Ubuntu 20.04 unexplainable boot failure (stuck at motherboard logo)

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I have a relatively new desktop PC (AMD Ryzen 7 5800X + AMD Radeon RX6700XT, MSI x570 gaming edge WIFI motherboard) that has been working nice with Ubuntu 20.04.3 (single operating system) for months. Today I installed a openssh server (by `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`) and setup remote desktop server (following instructions in https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=15733, with command `./xrdp-installer-1.2.1.sh -s`), and then it failed to reboot. Specifically, when booting it will stuck at motherboard logo (I have waited for more than 20 minutes). I have tried the following method and nothing works.

1. Boot into BIOS, reset all settings (secure boot is off), including reinstalling the battery on the motherboard.
2. The hard drive testing utility in MSI BIOS says my SSD that installed Ubuntu has no problem.
3. Create a new Ubuntu 20.04.3 LiveCD on USB disk, the PC can now boot into the grub menu of the liveCD, however:

   - If I select the first "Ubuntu" item, it immediately displays the motherboard logo and stuck forever again, but I remembered this menu works when I installed Ubuntu a few months ago.
   - If I select the second "Ubuntu (safe graphics)", it can boot into liveCD normally.
4. In the liveCD, I can mount the SSD and access the files normally. I tried `chroot` to the Ubuntu on SSD following the instructions in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery, and then deleted a few packages (xrdp, git, m4, autoconf) that the `xrdp-installer-1.2.1.sh` automatically installed. Reboot, still stuck at motherboard logo.
5. Boot into liveCD with safe graphics and `chroot` again, execute `apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`. Reboot, still stuck at motherboard logo.
6. Boot into liveCD with safe graphics, installed the "boot-repair" package, and tried boot repair. It finished with no errors, but after reboot it still stuck at motherboard logo.
7. Boot into liveCD with safe graphics and reinstall Ubuntu 20.04.3 on the same SSD (with the erase disk option). Installation finished with no error, but after reboot it still stuck at motherboard logo.
8. Remove the liveCD USB disk, press "ESC" when the computer boots, and it directly enters grub command line. Type `normal`, it then waits for about 1 second, and then shows the motherboard logo screen and stuck there.
9. Press "ESC" when the computer boots and enters grub command line. I then execute the following commands:

   - `set root=(hd1,gpt2)`  # This is the SSD partition with the newly installed Ubuntu
   - `linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-34-generic root=/dev/nvme0n1p2`
   - `initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-34-generic`
   - `boot`

It then quickly displayed many lines on the screen and get stuck. The following image shows the final screen contents. I found no apparent errors.
[image]

I am now completely lost. Can anyone gives some hints on what might cause the problem?